# How can I query referenced objects with the liquid content api

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have mapped out 3 content types with Liquid Content in DNN 9.1.1 Evoq Content, lets call them A, B and C. C has 1 or more references to B, B has 1 or more references to A, your standard 3 tier tree structure.

The visualizer I'm creating is a kind of expert system menu, it shows all of the 'A' data points, you click on one of the 'A' points, then it shows you all of the 'B' data points that reference the 'A' point you click and then the same down to 'C'.

It's easy to grab all of the 'A' points because I want all of them but when I get to 'B', I only want the ones that reference the 'A' I selected. There doesn't seem to be a way to query the data references of an object, there is just a general search query. I think the search query will work because the key of the selected 'A' data point is a UID such as 96645172-0457-47aa-ba9c-43acb6be8d82 but that just doesn't feel like it's the right way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. At the moment Liquid Content content items api does not provide such reference object query capabilities. Using searchText query string should work but as you point out, this will be a workaround.